# My Menu & Logo Image need to stretch to the very edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a website logo which sits under the menu which I would like both to stretch to the very edges of the screen regardless of the size screen viewing website. For the image I have tried many things including width: 100% and trying the background: cover; taking it outside of the  etc.

The html code for the menu:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="home.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
    <a href="gallery.php"><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Gallery</a>
    <a href="waitingpage.html"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i> Blog</a>
    <a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
</div>
```

Screenshot of the menu and the image: [image: Updated screenshot]

The image logo that sits under the menu neither stretches to the very edge of the screen:
html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-full"> 
        <a href="Index.html"><img class="Logo" src="Images/logo3.png" alt="Website Logo"></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS I have nothing for the class `Logo` anymore.. If there is anyone out there that can help stretch the menu AND the image to the very edge of the screen I would be so grateful.

Comment: please share screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @VarshaDhadge Just updated the screenshot, you can see that there are gaps on either side of the nabber menu and also the image, I was hoping for there to be no gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code. Hope that works for you.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.row{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align:center;
}
.row img{
    object-fit: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="home.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
    <a href="gallery.php"><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Gallery</a>
    <a href="waitingpage.html"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i> Blog</a>
    <a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-full"> 
        <a href="Index.html"><img class="Logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Website Logo"></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have put this into a code pen but I am unsure what exactly it is you want to be stretched across as stretching a 'logo' would be a bit strange.

I used this to target your div.row to stretch it across 100% of the DOM's view width - The same property can be used or tested on the logo but because this is a local file I can't test it.

```
.row {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(the border is just there to show you that its taking up the full width)

Comment: Hi Oliver, I'll check that out now, Ive updated the screenshot to show you the gaps I mean on either side of the menu and the image underneath

Answer (score 0):

if you want the navbar to be full page you need to add:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

i hope this is what you meant. with the image i cant help seeing it is local path.